# Lesser known string similarity metrics

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, string

This may be a hard question to answer but I'm researching something and I was wondering if anyone knew of "lesser known" string similarity metrics (see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) for examples of well-known ones). I've been to wikipedia and Sourceforge has a nice library called [Simmetrics](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/) with [a bunch of string metric algorithms](http://www.dcs.shef.ac.uk/~sam/stringmetrics.html). Has anyone done some research or has found some string algorithm that called your attention as not much used?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/stringCompare/read-me.html) (LingPipe) gives some tips about string comparisons.  It talks about Damerau-Levenstein distance, Needlman-Wunsch algorithm, Jaccard distance, Jaro-Winkler distance, TF/IDF distance.  Distance understood as similarity between two strings.

At the end of the page, it gives references and it also provides a Java implementation ready to be used ([download & license](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/web/download.html))

Answer (score 1):

There are also the class of phonetic algorithms (such as [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)) that might add to your list.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php
including all the "See Also" references and all the user comments.

Answer (score 0):

[SpSim](http://hlt.di.fct.unl.pt/luis/spsim/) (Spelling Similarity) is a string similarity measure targeted at identifying cross-language cognates (words having the same origin).