# String comparison

Tags: android, string, comparison

For my project, ppl can give an answer to a certain question they get. I perform `userAnswer = etUserAnswer.getText().toString().toLowerCase();` on it and then compare it to a value that is stored in the SQL database.

But I was thinking that it is quite annoying for a user if the answer is just almost correct but if he has written 'kk' in a word instead of 'ck'. Therefor I am trying to create a system which **checks if the answer is more or less correct** and then returns the result of this. I searched the net but don't seem to find anything on this subject. I also don't know if such a system has a certain name in english?

Or.. maybe somebody knows a good tutorial or a good way to get started?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Comment: You want something like the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) or the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for the string distance, for which you could e.g. use the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). For alternative metrics, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210637/lesser-known-string-similarity-metrics)